# Can I make my discord embed color different depending on whether I lose, win, or tie the game?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a rps command to play with the bot.
If I lose, I want the color of the embed to be red.
If I win, I want the color of the embed to be green.
If I tie, I want the color of the embed to be grey.

Here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def rps(ctx):
  options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "r", "p", "s"]
  ask_rps_em = discord.Embed(title="Rock, Paper or Scissors?", color=discord.Color.blue())
  await ctx.send(embed=ask_rps_em)
  def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel and m.content.lower() in options
  try:
    choice = (await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30.0)).content
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send("You didn't answer in time. Please try again.")
  if choice.lower() not in options:
    await ctx.send("Invalid choice. Please choose rock, paper, or scissors.")
    return
  bot_choice = random.choice(options)
  result = None
  if choice.lower() == "rock":
    if bot_choice == "rock":
      result = "It's a tie!"
      color = "cyan"
    elif bot_choice == "paper":
      result = "You lose! Paper beats rock."
      color = "red"
    elif bot_choice == "scissors":
      result = "You win! Rock beats scissors."
      color = "green"
  elif choice.lower() == "paper":
    if bot_choice == "rock":
      result = "You win! Paper beats rock."
      color = "green"
    elif bot_choice == "paper":
      result = "It's a tie!"
      color = "cyan"
    elif bot_choice == "scissors":
      result = "You lose! Scissors beats paper."
      color = "red"
  elif choice.lower() == "scissors":
    if bot_choice == "rock":
      result = "You lose! Rock beats scissors."
      color = "red"
    elif bot_choice == "paper":
      result = "You win! Scissors beats paper."
      color = "green"
    elif bot_choice == "scissors":
      result = "It's a tie!"
      color = "cyan"
  result_em = discord.Embed(title=f"You chose {choice.lower()}. I chose {bot_choice}. {result}", color=discord.Color.{color}()) # should it be like that or what?
  await ctx.send(embed=result_em)
```

I want the result_em's color to be that color but I don't know how. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can use integer color codes as well. `color=0xffffff`=white, `color=0x00ff00`=green, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, `discord.Color.{str}()` doesn't work. However, there isn't a point in you doing this when you can just set your variable `color` to a `discord.Color` right away.

```
  if choice.lower() == "rock":
    if bot_choice == "rock":
      result = "It's a tie!"
      color = discord.Color.light_grey()
    elif bot_choice == "paper":
      result = "You lose! Paper beats rock."
      color = discord.Color.red()
    elif bot_choice == "scissors":
      result = "You win! Rock beats scissors."
      color = discord.Color.green()
# rest of checks (ps: there is a shorter way of doing this with dictionaries)
  result_em = discord.Embed(title=f"You chose {choice.lower()}. I chose {bot_choice}. {result}", color=color) 
  await ctx.send(embed=result_em)
```

Not your question but your code also doesn't have to be so long. Using dictionaries, you can check for each case

```
@bot.command()
async def rps(ctx):
  options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
  ask_rps_em = discord.Embed(title="Rock, Paper or Scissors?", color=discord.Color.blue())
  await ctx.send(embed=ask_rps_em)
  def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel and m.content.lower() in options
  try:
    choice = (await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30.0)).content
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send("You didn't answer in time. Please try again.")
  if choice.lower() not in options:
    await ctx.send("Invalid choice. Please choose rock, paper, or scissors.")
    return
  bot_choice = random.choice(options)
  test = checkrps(bot_choice, choice.lower())
  result_em = discord.Embed(title=test[0], color=test[1])
  
winCases = {"rock": "scissors", "paper": "rock", "scissors": "paper"}
def checkrps(bots_choice, users_choice):
  if bots_choice == users_choice: # same choices
    return "It's a tie!", discord.Color.light_grey()
  elif winCases[users_choice] == bots_choice:
    return f"You win! {users_choice} beats {bots_choice}.", discord.Color.green()
  else: # if it isn't a tie nor win it is a loss
    return f"You lose! {bots_choice} beats {users_choice}", discord.Color.red()
```